# What is a polite way of saying someone is posh?

Tags: vocabulary

What's way of saying someone is posh that isn't rude? And without being over-aggrandising?

Comment: Try asking this on http://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agreed, sending this there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *posh* isn't considered a rude term in itself, nor do I think it excessively aggrandizes a subject, but if it's not the word you're looking for, this should be of help: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/posh

Answer (score 0):

I googled it and found https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/posh

Stylish, elegant, exclusive (expensive).
After the performance they went out to a very posh restaurant.